# Managing delivery of form data

Tags: php, forms, timer, delayed-execution, timedelay

I'm currently building a website with a form integrated to a specific page where people can leave their contact information. The website is constructed in PHP.

After submitting the form, the data is send to a database & I receive an e-mail that a new submission has occurred. This all works fine.

My question:

How can I manage the 'submission schedule' of this form? I want people to be able to enter their info any time of any day, but I only want the data send to the database on ma-fr between 08.00 and 21.00.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it isn't put into the database when they submit the form, where should it go instead?

Comment: Excellent question... temporary database perhaps?

Comment: I suspect what you really need is a notification schedule. Let it go in the DB right away, but only send you an email during those times. OR add a "status" field to the DB and mark them inactive when created off-hours, and then activate them later. If one of these Ideas will work, I'll try to help you make the adjustment.